# CronJob not working as expected

Tags: 14.04, cron, amazon-ec2

I generated a cronjob line for `crontab -e` with [Crontab Generator](http://www.crontab-generator.org/):

```
* */2 * * * curl http://www.example.com/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I was expecting that it should run every 2 hours. But in my Amazon server, the same line runs every 2 minutes instead of 2 hours. What's wrong with the above line? Can someone please guide me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `0 */2 * * *` istead of `* */2 * * *`.

Comment: `+1` Thanks I will check and let you know soon. `:)`